# Estimated distribution of maximal cliques in international social networks

Tags: social-networks, sociology

Let a [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) be a subset of the vertices of an undirected graph such that every two distinct vertices in the clique are adjacent. Let a maximal clique be a set of vertices that is a clique and also a [maximal set](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximalSet.html).

I'm open to answers that defer to the research study's operational definition of "relationship" in such networks. For example, either in-person or virtual relationships are fine. Social media networks are fine.

I am not asking about the mathematics of the model itself, nor about its computation. Tools like [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/clique.html) provide options for computation. Rather, I am asking if there are any instances of it in **Sociology** research, especially in an international context.

We might analogize to [factor analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis), which is a commonly-used model in [Psychometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychometrics). Factor analysis can be described quite precisely in terms of [Linear Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) and mathematical statistics.

Questions about estimator bias or matrix multiplication in factor analysis would be off-topic here. But, factor analysis is not off-topic when it intersects with its use in understanding [IQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient) or the [g-factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_factor_(psychometrics)).

Have any international estimates been made for the frequency distribution over the size (cardinalities) of the maximal cliques that humans participate in?

Comment: While [there are differences between Psychology and Sociology](https://www.nu.edu/resources/sociology-vs-psychology/), you may want to see [Is Sociology on topic?](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/254/7604) for a [meta] discussion.